# How to call function written in main file into ajax file in php & jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

Written a Jquery function in main file (index.php) & want to call same function in ajax file that is called from main file.

Comment: Give some more details and code please

Comment: we need more context.

Comment: I have write code for creating color for user rating. its work fine when write a review form added same page. But when we added write a review form using ajax the set rating function is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the function in the main page and you inject ajax to container inside it, the function need to be available for calling, in the end of the ajax file add 
  function() //main function

you can also choose another approach after the ajax success you can call the function directly... by passing it as callback for example:

```
ajax(url,mainFunction,true)


function ajax(url, callback, async) {
    var date = new Date();
    var ticks = date.getTime();

    if (url.indexOf('?') == -1)
        url = url + "?tick=" + ticks;
    else
        url = url + "&tick=" + ticks;


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        async: async == undefined ? true : async,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data != undefined)
                callback(data);
        },

        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           //throw error
        },

        complete: function () {

        }

    });
}
```